# Wordpress title... find tag in title and add Span / CSS to just matching tag

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, preg-replace

I am trying to find any titles that contain tags and `preg_replace` the matching tag so there is a `span` around it (to bold the tag).

This is what I have so far...  The following code is just adding the_tags() to the end of the title.  I am not too good with Wordpress and I know it's probably because the `the_tags()` function includes other code such as "Tagged: " and "&mindot;".

```
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php 
                    $title = the_title();
                    $tags = array(the_tags());
                    $tag = implode(' ',$tags);
                    $displaytitle = preg_replace($tag, '<span class="larger">$tag</span>', $title);

                    echo $displaytitle;

                ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have been working on this on and off for the past few hours and have yet to come up with something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not implode.

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $displaytitle = preg_replace($tag, "<span class=\"larger\">$tag</span>", $title);
}
```

should do the trick. Use double quotes to evalute variable inside.